# Android Facebook SDK4 - Track progress of phot upload

Tags: android, facebook, progressdialog, android-progressbar, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am developing an app that allows the user to upload a photo on his timeline using Facebook SDK 4.
At the time, I did the "upload photo on Facebook" and I did a draft of the progress dialog.

The problem is that the two things don't cooperate together. The progress bar doesn't show the real progress percentage.

My question is: **how can I "attach" the progressDialog to the "upload photo on Facebook"?**

Code **to share an image**.

```
private void sharePostOnFacebook() {
    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath);

    SharePhoto sharePhoto = new SharePhoto.Builder()
            .setBitmap(image)
            .setCaption(mPostContent)
            .build();

    SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
            .addPhoto(sharePhoto)
            .build();

    // Check if the user already has publish permission
    if (hasPublishPermission()) {
        ShareApi.share(content, shareCallback);
        showProgress();
    } else {
        List<String> publishPermission = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");
        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithPublishPermissions(this, publishPermission);
        sharePostOnFacebook();
    }
}
```

This is the **callback method** to manage the result of the `ShareApi.share`.

```
private FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result> shareCallback = new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {
    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        progress.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException error) {
        progress.dismiss();

        String title = getString(R.string.fb_share_error);
        String alertMessage = error.getMessage();
        showResult(title, alertMessage);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {
        progress.dismiss();

        if (result.getPostId() != null) {
            String title = getString(R.string.fb_share_success);
            String id = result.getPostId();
            String alertMessage = getString(R.string.successfully_posted_post, id);
            showResult(title, alertMessage);
        }
    }

    private void showResult(String title, String alertMessage) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setTitle(title)
                .setMessage(alertMessage)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.fb_share_ok, null)
                .show();
    }
};
```

At last, the `showProgess()` method in which the **progressDialog is created**.

```
private void showProgress() {
    progress = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
    progress.setCancelable(true);
    progress.setMessage("Upload Photo");
    progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    progress.setIndeterminate(true);
    progress.setProgress(0);
    progress.show();

    final int totalProgressTime = 100;
    final Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int jumpTime = 0;

            while (jumpTime < totalProgressTime) {
                try {
                    sleep(200);
                    jumpTime += 5;
                    progress.setProgress(jumpTime);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException exc) {
                    exc.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    };
    thread.start();
}
```

Comment: If it does not show the real percentage, what *does* it say?